# VBoxClient: VBoxClient (seamless): failed to start. Stage: Setting guest IRQ filter mask Error: VERR_INTERNAL_ERROR

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox

Is there solutions to fix this error:

> VBoxClient: VBoxClient (seamless): failed to start. Stage: Setting
>   guest IRQ filter mask Error: VERR_INTERNAL_ERROR

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBoxClient (seamless): failed to start. Stage: Setting guest IRQ filter mask Error: VERR\_INTERNAL\_ERROR](https://askubuntu.com/questions/985815/vboxclient-seamless-failed-to-start-stage-setting-guest-irq-filter-mask-err)

Answer (score 0):

Virtual Box and Guest Additions **v6.0.6** has released and fixed this problem
(For v5.x.x, it would be *v5.2.28* or later).

Update Virtual Box **Guest Additions on Guest OS**,
following Virtual Box and Guest Additions update on Host OS.

Comment: 6.0.8 does not fix this issue for me.

Comment: Have you updated Guest Additions? If not yet, perhaps you need to do [Devices] -> [Insert Guest Additions CD Image] from Virtual Box menu, and reinstall it into Guest.

Comment: I did update them.